# Mongoose: findByIdAndRemove and forEach doesn't work in nested array object

Tags: express, mongoose, foreach, mongoose-schema

**Problem 1**: I have a Model with the array of objects and one object contains multiple objects I want to remove the main object with findByIdAndRemove but the associated object didn't remove. can anybody give me any hint so that I can resolve it?
**blogSchema**

```
var blogSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    image:String,
    body:{type:String, default:""},
    created:{ type: Date },
  comments:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Comment'
  }]
});
```

**commentSchema**

```
var commentSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    text:String,
    author:String
})
```

Here what I tried:

```
app.delete('/blogs/:id',function(req,res,next){
    //destroy blog
    Blog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id,function(err){
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/blogs')
        }else{
            res.redirect('/blogs')
        }
    })
})
```

But it delete only my blog **not comments** which is associated with blog.
**Problem 2**: one small issue in `/blogs/:id` while rendering show.ejs. `/blogs/:id` GET fetches just that one blog with associated comments. if I coded `<%=blog.comments%>` in show.ejs then it returns

```
 { author: 'emon ', text: 'comment 1', _id: 5d87027848e59703a4d4a935, __v: 0 },
{ author: 'emon ', text: 'comment 2\r\n', _id: 5d87028848e59703a4d4a936, __v: 0 }
```

which mean it perfectly work but if I coded :

```
<%blog.comments.forEach(function(comment)%>
<p><strong><%=comment.author%></strong>-<%=comment.text%></p>
)%>
```

it give me **SyntaxError**. 
**Full Error**:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\views\blogs\show.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass async: true as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:392:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\app.js:77:8
    at C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4616:16
    at C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:264:16
    at C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4320:11
    at C:\Users\websi\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\RESTfulBlogApp\v3\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Sorry for asking too many questions in one.  Thanks for your time.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

**For Problem 1:** As MongoDB is not a relational DB, There is not any built-in feature available for it. You have to Delete all comments of a blog by making the query and for that, you have to create comment schema accordingly.

If you are are using mongoose ODM, You can try mongoose middlewares to reduce your efforts for predefined queries

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

but you have to manage Schema accordingly so that you can find all the required comments

**For Problem 2:**
 Give It a Try

```
<% for(var i=0; i<blog.comments.length; i++) {%> <p><strong><%=blog.comments[i].author%></strong>-<%=blog.comments[i].text%></p>> <% } %>
```

Comment: I am newly introduced with MongoDB so have no idea how to manage Schema to get ride of that. Anyway maybe relational DB play a good role here. But can you help me to resolve my second problem which seem silly but I can't fix it @Ankit Manchanda Sir

Comment: <% for(var i=0; i<blog.comments.length; i++) {%>
   <p><strong><%=blog.comments[i].author%></strong>-<%=blog.comments[i].text%></p>>
<% } %>


Give It a Try

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre hook of mongoose e.g

```
blogSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Comment.remove({author: this._id}).exec(); // Comment model
    next();
});
```

See more https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Here is a working example of code https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/task-api/blob/master/src/models/User.js#L158-L168

This should work

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // import mongoose
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; // extract schema for easy use

// declare blogSchema
const blogSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  body: { type: String, default: '' },
  created: { type: Date },
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comment'
    }
  ]
});

const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema); // Blog model

const commentSchema = Schema({
  text: String,
  author: String
});
const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema); // Comment model
blogSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  Comment.remove({ author: this._id }).exec(); // Comment model
  next();
});

module.exports = { Blog, Comment };

// Now import Blog here
app.delete('/blogs/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  //destroy blog
  Blog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: strange!!! I expected that will be worked. But still I find those comment in `db.comments.find()` Here what I tried: https://pastebin.com/VGQqfGkq @ARIF MAHMUD RANA Sir

Comment: @emonhossain you have to import your comment Model see https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/task-api/blob/master/src/models/User.js#L6 I don't find your comment model here https://pastebin.com/VGQqfGkq

Comment: Ok I added my comment Model `const Comment=require('./comment');` but still same problem Sir

Comment: one last question then my `models/blog.js` and `models/comment.js` combined with one file. How could I export them in `app.js`. Because currently I used `Blog=require('./models/blog');
Comment=require('./models/comment');` I always split those model and save different file. So no idea how to use it in `app.js` :) Can you tell me please?

Comment: @emonhossain You can always split this into separate files & make default exports but the key point is the hook. When you are removing blog the pre hook will be called & you cleanup here then you delete. Here as you are cleaning/removing comment when blog deleted so you have to import comment model here & remove matched comment. You can check my repo for more details https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/task-api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199926/discussion-between-emonhossain-and-arif-mahmud-rana).